# postMessage and postMessageAndAwaitResponse?

Tags: google-nativeclient

In javascript,I call postMessage at fitst,and then call postMessageAndAwaitResponse.

```
var ret;
naclModule.postMessage(msg);
ret = naclModule.postMessageAndAwaitResponse(msg);
```

and the implementation of pp::MessageHandler in my C++ application is:

```
void HandleMessage(pp::InstanceHandle instance, const pp::Var& var_message)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10000; ++j)
            ++m_iRetVal;
    }
}
```

and the HandleBlockingMessage is:

```
pp::Var HandleBlockingMessage(pp::InstanceHandle instance, const pp::Var& var_message) 
{
    return pp::Var(m_iRetVal);
}
```

the m_iRetVal is class data member.

I tested this programe,  and the return value of postMessageAndAwaitResponse was always 100000000. And i wanna know if the HandleBlockingMessage always executed after HandleMessage finished in this situation?
I want call postMessage, to do a large number of calculation int HandleMessage(maybe cost a long time),and call postMessageAndAwaitResponse to get the result of calculation. can i to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is guaranteed that the order of the messages is preserved. Unfortunately, I don't think our API documentation mentions this. But we've taken great pains to make sure messages arrive in order. So you can be sure that when you call postMessage and then postMessageAndAwaitResponse afterward, the NaCl side will receive the first one (with HandleMessage) before the second one (HandleBlockingMessage).

There's a comment here about it, and some of the code that makes sure of it:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/content/renderer/pepper/message_channel.cc&l=317